# How can i increase MultinomialNB()'s accuracy score using sklearn and visualize the result in graph using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes, multinomial

I'm working on a data-set that looks like this : [image: this]

In my attached screenshot you can see my data-set contains 16 rows and 12 tuples but actually it is containing 521 rows and 12 tuples.

- 1st column is : "Menarche start early"
- 2nd column : "Oral Contraception"
- 3rd column : "Diet Maintain"
- 4th column : "Affected By Breast Cancer"
- 5th column : "Affected By cervical Cancer?"
- 6th column : "Cancer History In family?"
- 7th column : "Education?"
- 8th column : "Age of Husband"
- 9th column : "Menopause End age?"
- 10th column : "Food contains high fat?"
- 11th column : "Abortion?"
- 12th column : "Affected by ovarian Cancer?".

Here all the columns contain categorical variables. So I preprocessed the data-set by using LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder and to avoid dummy variable trap I've dropped the 1st column of dummy variables that creates more than 2 columns.

Then I have splitted the data-set into 2 parts with test_size = 0.25 and random_state = 18, then I fitted X_train and y_train to MultinomialNB() and got accuracy score 0.7938931297709924.

Then i constructed few learning curves that looks like this [image: this] 
and
this  [image: this one] 
but most importantly my model is giving value for R-squared:  0.557 and Adj. R-squared: 0.543 which isn't good i assume.

Here is my confusion matrix [image: confusion matrix]
 I want both r squared and adj r squared value somewhere around 1 but i am not understanding how can i do that efficiently as i am new in this area and haven't worked before with any data set that contains all the categorical variables and no values,please help me with this to make my model better using naive bayes algorithm also if you find any error in my model,please let me know and help and also please help me by giving resources and tutorials+code examples to construct data visualization graph from my model.here is my code for this project :

---

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

#Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('RiskFactor.csv')
X =  dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 11].values
#dummy_x = dataset.iloc[:, [0,6,7,8]].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,0] ) #Menarche start early

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,1] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,1] )

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,2] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,2] )

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,3] )

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,4] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,4] ) 
label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,5] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,5] )

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,6] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,6] ) #Education

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,7] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,7] ) #Age of Husband

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,8] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,8] ) #Menopause End age?

label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,9] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,9] )


label_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:,10] = label_x.fit_transform(X[:,10] )

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = "all")
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()


#avoiding dummy variable trap by removing extra columns 

X = X[: ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]


# Encoding the Dependent Variable

labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size =0.25,
random_state = 18)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB,BernoulliNB,MultinomialNB

classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(classifier)

y_expect = y_test



#predicting the test set result

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

#Making the Confusion Matrix

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score

cm = confusion_matrix (y_test, y_pred)


print(accuracy_score(y_expect,y_pred))


# finding P value from statsmodels

import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=y,exog = X).fit()

regressor_OLS.summary()

from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit


def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                    n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):
"""
Generate a simple plot of the test and training learning curve.

Parameters
----------
estimator : object type that implements the "fit" and "predict" methods
    An object of that type which is cloned for each validation.

title : string
    Title for the chart.

X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
    Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and
    n_features is the number of features.

y : array-like, shape (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_features), optional
    Target relative to X for classification or regression;
    None for unsupervised learning.

ylim : tuple, shape (ymin, ymax), optional
    Defines minimum and maximum yvalues plotted.

cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
    Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
    Possible inputs for cv are:
      - None, to use the default 3-fold cross-validation,
      - integer, to specify the number of folds.
      - An object to be used as a cross-validation generator.
      - An iterable yielding train/test splits.

    For integer/None inputs, if ``y`` is binary or multiclass,
    :param train_sizes:
    :class:`StratifiedKFold` used. If the estimator is not a classifier
    or if ``y`` is neither binary nor multiclass, :class:`KFold` is used.

    Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
    cross-validators that can be used here.

 n_jobs : integer, optional
    Number of jobs to run in parallel (default 1).
"""
plt.figure()
plt.title(title)
if ylim is not None:
    plt.ylim(*ylim)
plt.xlabel("Training examples")
plt.ylabel("Score")
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
plt.grid()

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                 color="r")
plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
         label="Training score")
plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
         label="Cross-validation score")

plt.legend(loc="best")
return plt



estimator = MultinomialNB()


title = "Learning Curves (Naive Bayes classifier ALGORITHM)"
# Cross validation with 100 iterations to get smoother mean test and train
# score curves, each time with 20% data randomly selected as a validation    

#set.
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=100, test_size=0.25, random_state=17)

#cv = None
plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=(0.7, 1.01), cv=cv,    
n_jobs=1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Why are you doing this: `X[: ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]`? You taken columns 1 - 26 in your features? How do you know these are the columns that drop the dummy variable trap?

Comment: @VivekKumar  thanks for your reply but you've misunderstood a little bit mate,look carefully again,i am not taking all 1-26 columns,,,,i have dropped 0, 13, 16, 19 number columns and took the remaining columns.from variable explorer i first analyzed which one's are the 1st column of those dummy variables that creates more than 2 columns,i found column number 0, 13, 16, 19 are the ones ,so i removed those columns,also if i remove that line "X = X[: ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]" and recompile my model i get accuracy score 0.7862595419847328

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: @VivekKumar it's okay mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I've solved this problem by using PCA ,here is the code :   


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 31 22:38:32 2018

@author: MOBASSIR
"""


# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd




#Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('ovarian.csv')
X =  dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 11].values
#dummy_x = dataset.iloc[:, [0,6,7,8]].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

label_x1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = label_x1.fit_transform(X[:,0] ) #Menarche start early



label_x2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,1] = label_x2.fit_transform(X[:,1] )

label_x3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,2] = label_x3.fit_transform(X[:,2] )


label_x4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = label_x4.fit_transform(X[:,3] )


label_x5 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,4] = label_x5.fit_transform(X[:,4] )


label_x6 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,5] = label_x6.fit_transform(X[:,5] )


label_x7 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,6] = label_x7.fit_transform(X[:,6] ) #Education




label_x8 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,7] = label_x8.fit_transform(X[:,7] ) #Age of Husband




label_x9 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,8] = label_x9.fit_transform(X[:,8] ) #Menopause End age?




label_x10 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,9] = label_x10.fit_transform(X[:,9] )




label_x11 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,10] = label_x11.fit_transform(X[:,10] )




onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,6,7,8])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()


# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap

"""

idx_to_delete = [0, 13, 16, 19]
X = [i for i in range(X.shape[-1]) if i not in idx_to_delete]

X = X[:, 1:]


df = pd.DataFrame(X, dtype='float64')


df = pd.to_numeric(X)

"""


#avoiding dummy variable trap by removing extra columns

#X = X[: ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]

"""
#4,8,10,12,18,21,22,23 for dropped columns
#5,9,11,13,19,22,23,24 for dropped columns
#1,4,5,6 == 2,5,6,7
X = X[: ,[9,11,23,24]]
"""

 #24,21,19,18,17,14,12,10,8,7,6 ,4 ,3 ,2,1 for undropped column
 #25,22,20,19,18,15,13,11,9,8,7 ,5 ,4 ,3,2
 #2,5,6,8,12,15
X = X[: ,[9,13,16,18,19]]


# Encoding the Dependent Variable

labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
"""
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
y= onehotencoder.fit_transform(y).toarray()
"""





# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)




# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)




# Applying PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test)
explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_






#Applying naive bayes classifier

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB,BernoulliNB,MultinomialNB

classifier = BernoulliNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(classifier)

y_expect = y_test



#predicting the test set result

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

#Making the Confusion Matrix

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score

cm = confusion_matrix (y_test, y_pred)


print(accuracy_score(y_expect,y_pred))





# finding P value from statsmodels

import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=y,exog = X).fit()

regressor_OLS.summary()




from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

ck =  BernoulliNB()
scores = cross_val_score(ck,X,y,cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print (scores)

print (scores.mean())




from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit

def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):



    '''Generate a simple plot of the test and training learning curve.

   Parameters
   ----------
   estimator : object type that implements the "fit" and "predict" methods
       An object of that type which is cloned for each validation.

   title : string
       Title for the chart.

   X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
       Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and
       n_features is the number of features.

   y : array-like, shape (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_features), optional
       Target relative to X for classification or regression;
       None for unsupervised learning.

   ylim : tuple, shape (ymin, ymax), optional
       Defines minimum and maximum yvalues plotted.

   cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
       Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
       Possible inputs for cv are:
         - None, to use the default 3-fold cross-validation,
         - integer, to specify the number of folds.
         - An object to be used as a cross-validation generator.
         - An iterable yielding train/test splits.

       For integer/None inputs, if ``y`` is binary or multiclass,
       :param train_sizes:
       :class:`StratifiedKFold` used. If the estimator is not a classifier
       or if ``y`` is neither binary nor multiclass, :class:`KFold` is used.

       Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
       cross-validators that can be used here.

   n_jobs : integer, optional
       Number of jobs to run in parallel (default 1).'''


    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt



estimator = BernoulliNB()


title = "Learning Curves (Naive Bayes classifier ALGORITHM)"
# Cross validation with 100 iterations to get smoother mean test and train
# score curves, each time with 20% data randomly selected as a validation set.
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=100, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=(0.7, 1.01), cv=cv, n_jobs=1)

plt.show()

#End of Bayes theorem


plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 14

plt.hist(y_pred, bins = 8)

plt.xlim(0, 1)

plt.title('Predicted probabilities')
plt.xlabel('Affected by ovarian cancer?(predicted)')
plt.ylabel('frequency')




from sklearn.metrics import recall_score,precision_score

recall_score(y_test,y_pred,average='macro')

precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')








# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Naive Bayes (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Visualising the Test set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Naive Bayes (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```